# InfluxDB schema/measurement design

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2

I'm using the Influx C# Client to add some telemetry to a server application.
Should I create multiple measurements to capture the different types of events eg.
`sql_connection_error`, `user_login` etc.
Or should I have just one measurement eg `myApplication` used throughout, and then have use different fields for the above events eg. `sql_connection_error` etc?
or asked another way, what's better:

```
"mysql_connection_error,database=dbname,server=serverName,uid=prodUser error=1044i <TIMESTAMP>"
"userLogin,server=serverName,uid=prodUser user=userName <TIMESTAMP>"
```

Or

```
"myApplication,database=dbname,server=serverName,uid=prodUser mysql_connection_error=1044i <TIMESTAMP>"
"myApplication,server=serverName,uid=prodUser user_login=userName <TIMESTAMP>"
```

Is it preferable to have all measurements share the same set of tag-keys? (edited)